# How to solve infinite recursion in java (stack overflow)?

Tags: java

I have problem with infinite recursion. Main method will run, then if I chose 1, it will go to submenu(). But, when I choose a wrong option in submenu(), the program must be loop back to main method.

However, this situation can result stack overflow.

Do you have any ideas guys related to this problem? How could the it loop back to main method without calling the main()?

Thanks a lot guys.

```
   public void main() {
      // variables omitted
      while (menu) {

         switch (option) {
         case 1:
            subMenu();
            break;
         }
      }

   }

   public void subMenu() {
      switch (a) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      default:
         System.out.println("Invalid Option");
         main();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Solution: don't use recursion here as it would be much better to simply use a while loop.

Comment: you already have a while menu in main.. so why not just return?
instead of main() do return?

Comment: Consider having your subMenu method return a value, it could be as simple as a boolean, to let the calling code know whether it was successful or not, and if not, then continue with the while loop.

Comment: Also: what does this have to do with javascript? That tag just makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call `main()` to return to the main method, to return from a method, you say `return <vairable>`, or if the method is a void return type, no return is needed at the end of the method. You can still say `return` if you want to return from a place that is not the end of the method.

So in your case above, the `switch` is the last element in the `subMenu` method, so after the switch, the method is finished, so returns. Just remove the call to `main()`.

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: Thanks Noel for the answer. Thats very helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Im newbie in java.